# Как узнать количество выполненных/оставшихся запросов в сутки для ключа?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, geocoding, геокодинг

Мы сгенерировали ключ в кабинете разработчика для геокодирования. У ключа ограничение 25 тысяч запросов в сутки.

Возможно ли используя API Яндекса узнать, сколько запросов за сутки было сделано или сколько еще запросов осталось?

Comment: @Reni Почему вы удалили свой ответ? Он в корне неверный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настоящее время у кабинета разработчика Яндекса есть свой API.

В его документации написано, как узнать лимиты API и количество выполненных запросов.

Для запроса нужно подготовить входные данные:

1. [Подключить API Кабинета разработчика](https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/api/auth-docpage/) и получить X-Auth-Key.
2. Определить [идентификатор проекта](https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/api/get-projects-docpage/).
3. Определить [идентификатор сервиса](https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/api/get-services-docpage/).

Теперь чтобы посмотреть параметры лимита запросов к API сервисов, используйте HTTP-запрос с методом GET:

```
GET /projects/<project_id>/services/<service_id>/limits
Host:  https://api-developer.tech.yandex.net
X-Auth-Key:  <ключ API Кабинета разработчика>
```

Ответ вернёт как суточный лимит "limit", так и количество выполненных запросов "value". Определить остаток будет несложно. =)